# K-fold validation vs random sampling k times

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation

Why do people choose to use k-fold validation instead of using random sampling k times?

Comment: I disagree that it is too broad, but it fits better to http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

Because with k times random sampling, certain objects will be sampled too often, and many objects will not be sampled at all (a surprisingly large amount for a useful k!).

K-fold cross validation guarantees that every object is used k-1 times for learning, and 1 time for testing. This yields more stable results, every data point is equally important.